# Rails: Submitting an array of child elements

Tags: ruby, forms, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to submit a form which is supposed to have an array of child elements. I'm not sure if I have it correctly. Can somebody help me refactor?

I have a couple of models `user` and `item`. A user`has_many :items`.

The form that sends the information for user and items look like the following -

```
<%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
   <% f.text_field :name %>
   <% f.fields_for :items do |item| %>
      <% item.text_field :name %>
      <% item.text_field :price %>
   <% end %>
<% end %>
```

I have the following in my controller -

```
def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
    @items = @user.items.build(item_params)

    if @items.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }          
    end

    format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created. But there was a problem saving the items.' }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @userd.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


private
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name)
    end

    def item_params
      params.require(:user).require(:item).permit(:name, :price)
    end
```

When I save the `user`, only 1 record of `items` get saved, meaning - the data isn't being passed as an array of objects. How do I get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few corrections to be made in your code.

In your `users_controller`

```
def new
 @user = User.new
 3.times do #this will generate three records of items
 @user.items.build
 end
end

def create
@user = User.new(user_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @user.save
      format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }          
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @userd.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end


private
def user_params
   params.require(:user).permit(:name,items_attributes: [:name,price])
end
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like right now you are only ever telling Rails to build one `item` object. Your form is passing up the two parameters for an item, and in your controller you call `build` once, so `@items` is only ever set equal to the single `Item` returned by `build`. Unless their are hidden parts of your form you aren't showing, it looks like you're only setting one set of options for a `user`'s `items`. If your goal is to have an array of many `items` with identical parameters, the fastest fix would be to just do this within the logic of your `create` action. There are many ways you could implement that (here is one simple way):

```
@items = []
x.times { @items << @user.items.build(item_params) }
```

If you're looking to send a request from the form with multiple unique `items`, you'll have to add more fields to your form, since currently you are only sending one set of parameters.

Comment: Nice! Any idea how I can find ′x′? Or any other alternatives? I can have x as a constant, which might not be the case in some circumstances.

Comment: Also, I get an "undefined method `save' for #<Array:0x007fdd7741a760>" at the line @hours.save

Comment: If you are just going for duplicates of the same kind of `item` and want the user to dictate how many, you could add a form field that passes the number of items you want. Otherwise you'd have to decide for yourself, using a constant or otherwise.

You haven't posted any code with `@hours`, but saving an array to the database shouldn't work. If you're trying to get things to persist beyond a single request, you'll need to either add columns to your `users` resource or create new resources.

Comment: Apologies..  `@items`, not `@hours`. I'm trying to save each item in @items, not the array itself

Comment: If you want them in the database, you'll need to create an `items` resource if you haven't already- a table in the database and a corresponding model with associations to `users`. A `user` would `has_many :items` and an `item` would `belong_to :user`, based on the relationship you're portraying.